# How should I consider OS virtual memory mechanism as developer

Tags: performance, operating-system, virtual-memory

Modern OS provides virtual memory abstraction for processes. When process request particular virtual memory page missing in RAM, OS should find virtual page to unload from RAM to swap and load necessary page from swap to RAM. Read/Write to disk is an expensive operations compare to RAM operations. Am I right?

How should I consider those virtual memory - swap OS mechanisms as a software developer (not system layer)? When and how I should treat my data and algorithms to avoid missing virtual pages and swapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: Yes, very.

Q2:

The beauty of virtual memory is that the developer has to do very little.

The main problem for developers to avoid is to minimize jumping around in memory.

Access large multidimensional array using indices so that you access adjacent elements.

Try to work with one big array at a time.

Those same rule tend to help with processor caches as well.